# how to create Login with nodejs (express) and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, session, express

Halo, Im a nodejs newbie

I followed these codes but came out with error session ( 500 TypeError: Cannot set property 'regenrate' of undefined, 500 TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined, ETC....

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var hash = require('./pass').hash;


var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 2000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

//app.locals.error ='';

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser('shhhh, very secret'));
app.use(express.session());


function restrict(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.user) {
    next();
  } else {
    req.session.error = 'Access denied!';
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
}

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
   response.send('This is the homepage');
});

app.get('/login', function(request, response) {
   response.send('<form method="post" action="/login">' +
  '<p>' +
    '<label>Username:</label>' +
    '<input type="text" name="username">' +
  '</p>' +
  '<p>' +
    '<label>Password:</label>' +
    '<input type="text" name="password">' +
  '</p>' +
  '<p>' +
    '<input type="submit" value="Login">' +
  '</p>' +
  '</form>');
});

app.post('/login', function(request, response) {

    var username = request.body.username;
    var password = request.body.password;
     request.session.user = username;

});

app.get('/logout', function(request, response){
    request.session.destroy(function(){
        response.redirect('/');
    });
});

app.get('/restricted', restrict, function(request, response){
  response.send('This is the restricted area! Hello ' + request.session.user + '! click <a href="/logout">here to logout</a>');
});



/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Create server
----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

I was googling it but no even a single example found

Comment: Try removing the line `app.use(app.router);`

Comment: while robertklep's probably right, also show the full actual error, don't paraphrase it. That error comes with a stack trace that tells you exactly where things are going wrong, and will tell you the line in app.js as well as the deeper code where your error is.

Comment: –  robertklep  : Thanks man...it works , –  Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans : Thanks...i'll give that a shot